# what might cause the SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 522)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

the app may have multiple threads that are accessing the sqlite database. In one function it does a simple query:

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

final Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, Data.PROJECTION,
            Data.Id + "=?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
```

The app works most of the time but saw reported crashes on this resolver.query line.

```
SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 522)
#################################################################
Error Code : 522 (SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ)
Caused By : Disk I/O error occurred during 'short read' operation.
(disk I/O error (code 522))
```

saw on https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_short_read

(522) SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ

The SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ error code is an extended error code for SQLITE_IOERR indicating that a read attempt in the VFS layer was unable to obtain as many bytes as was requested. This might be due to a truncated file.

not sure how to read it.
What could be the cause of this 522 error. If it is caused by some other thread is accessing the database, how to make sure this resolver.query() is not interrupted by other thread (same for other thread's database query)?

the database is

```
mOpenHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, version);
```

and the query/update/... are like

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // simplified snippet    
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selection, selectionArgs);

    return cursor;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    // simplified snippet  

    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = selection;
    SQLiteStatement updateStatement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    int numberOfRowsUpdated = updateStatement.executeUpdateDelete();
    return numberOfRowsUpdated;

}
```

Comment: The database file got corrupted. Replace it with the latest backup.

Comment: thanks CL! restart the app it works fine. Not sure if it is databse file corrupted. Not sure how to replace the database file from the backup on Android, any suggestion?